# Is incrementing a _Bool defined?

Tags: c, boolean, increment, undefined-behavior

A _Bool is defined by the C standard to be an unsigned type containing either 0 or 1. If a value of 1 of type _Bool is incremented, there are, as far as I can see, two options:

- The value wraps around from 1 to 0
- The value is incremented to 2, which is nonzero, and hence is changed into 1 when converted back to a _Bool

On GCC and Clang on my system, the behaviour seems to be the latter. Is this well-defined by the standard?

Comment: gcc 8.3.1, when you enable full warnings, objects with "warning: increment of a boolean expression [-Wbool-operation]", which suggests is not well defined. Curiously, clang 5.0.1 doesn't seem to object.

Comment: Interesting results on gcc 8.3.1: incrementing a bool goes from 0 to 1, but doing it again keeps it at one, but decrementing swaps it between 0 and 1 repeatedly - I think decrement is doing an XOR.

Comment: @SteveFriedl It is logical as _Bool converted to the scalar value can have only value 0 or 1. No other values are permitted

Comment: Sure, but the OP found values of 2 after ++. This suggests to me that doing this is not well defined, so you probably should not assume any portable/reliable behavior for it.

Comment: Hey OP: which versions of gcc and clang are you using?

Comment: clang 10 doesn't give a warning either fwiw.

Comment: @SteveFriedl he has not. Read the question carefully

Comment: @P__J__ - I did read it carefully.  Perhaps they only imagined the 2 as part of some hypothetical calculation rather than actually saw it literally somewhere in (say) the assembler output.

Comment: integer promotion

Comment: It's funny how `--x;` can be used to toggle boolean value.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From the C Standard (6.3.1.2 Boolean type)

> 1 When any scalar value is converted to _Bool, the result is 0 if the
>   value compares equal to 0; otherwise, the result is 1.

And for example 6.5.3.1 Prefix increment and decrement operators

> 2 The value of the operand of the prefix ++ operator is incremented.
>   The result is the new value of the operand after incrementation. **The
>   expression ++E is equivalent to (E+=1**).

And at last 6.5.16.2 Compound assignment

> 3 **A compound assignment of the form E1 op = E2 is equivalent to the
>   simple assignment expression E1 = E1 op (E2),** except that the lvalue
>   E1 is evaluated only once, and with respect to an
>   indeterminately-sequenced function call, the operation of a compound
>   assignment is a single evaluation. If E1 has an atomic  type, compound
>   assignment is a read-modify-write operation with memory_order_seq_cst
>   memory order semantics.

Pay attention to that (6.3 Conversions)

> — The rank of _Bool shall be less than the rank of all other standard
>   integer types.

So used in expressions the type _Bool is converted to other types with a greater rank.

Comment: You should also mention integer promotions.

Comment: @dbush I think it does not matter relative to the question.

Comment: Without promotion, the value would wrap around.

Comment: @dbush No, this will not be.  According to the first quote any non-zero value is converted to 1. neither wrapping takes place.

Comment: But first you need to get a value of 2.  In the absence of integer promotions, incrementing a `_Bool` value of 1 will wrap around to a value of 0.

Comment: @dbush One more it does not matter. If to consider the operator ++ as Eq = E1 op E2 it is unimportant what is the type of the right side expression. It is important only whether it is zero or not.

Comment: @dbush It is obvious that when such an expression like E1 op E2  is evaluated the compiler determines the common type of the operands.

Answer (score 2):

As the __Bool converted to the scalar can have value of  0 or 1, the actual increment operation is an equivalent to

```
__Bool x = false;
int v = x;
v = !!(v + 1);
x = v;
```